# React filter array based on this.props.params.id

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following component:

```
import React from 'react';

import porgectsCollection from './../data/projectInfo.js';

class SingleProject extends React.Component {
  getProjectId() {
    let projectID = porgectsCollection.filter(el => {
        return (el.title = {this.props.params.id});
    });
  }
  render () {
    console.log(this.getProjectId);
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>{this.props.params.id}</h2>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SingleProject;
```

and my routes.jsx as follow:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Router, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import Wrapper from './../wrapper.jsx';
import Home from './../home.jsx';
import Projects from './../projects.jsx';
import SingleProject from './../singleProject.jsx';

ReactDOM.render((
    <Router>
        <Route component={Wrapper} >
            <Route path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="projects" component={Projects} />
            <Route path="projects/:id" component={SingleProject} />
        </Route>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

Based on the id passed in:

```
<Route path="projects/:id" component={SingleProject} />
```

I want to get that value and filter through the array coming from:

```
import porgectsCollection from './../data/projectInfo.js';
```

I am then trying to use this function:

```
  getProjectId() {
    let projectID = porgectsCollection.filter(el => {
        return (el.title = {this.props.params.id});
    });
  }
```

to display the correct data.

I am not sure if this is the right approach however I am also getting an error when I run webpack:

*unexpected token referring to {this.props.params.id}*

Comment: {this.props.params.id} curly braces are not required, curly braces are used only when you want to right javascript inside jsx , like you did in <h2>{this.props.params.id}</h2>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't need the brackets - it is just in a normal JS function:

```
  getProjectId() {
    let projectID = porgectsCollection.filter(el => {
        return el.title === this.props.params.id;
    });
  }
```

Some shinier formatting:

```
  getProjectId() {
    return porgectsCollection.filter(el => el.title === this.props.params.id);
  }
```

(also you made a typo in "projects" but I left it to be consistent)